# Equivalent of MATLAB’s caxis in OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

Recently, I used the OpenCV library to process the gray image, and I used the MATLAB platform to process (it works well), just like this:

```
imagesc(I), colormap 'Jet',caxis[0 1];%want to show the Pseudocolor picture
```

As you see, MATLAB has a function called `caxis`, which used to scale Pseudocolor axis.

My question is, are there any functions in OpenCV that can realize the `caxis` function of MATLAB or how should I realize this function?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the [applyColorMap](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html) function. However it's always a mapping for values between 0 and 255, even if all your image's pixels have their value between 20 and 30 (for example).

If you want to apply the whole colormap between your min and max values, you will need to have an intermediary mapping to "normalize" your values to a [0-255] scale. Or you could also create your own Color Map that would take a min and a max as arguments and create its full table accordingly.