# Set colour limit axis in OpenCV 4 (c++) akin to Matlab's CAXIS

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

Matlab offers the ability to set colour limits for the current axis using [CAXIS](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html). OpenCV has [applyColorMap](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html#gadf478a5e5ff49d8aa24e726ea6f65d15) which can be used to highlight differences in pixel intensity in a greyscale image which I believe maps pixel from 0 - 255.

I am new to Matlab/Image-processing and have been asked to port a simple program from MatLab which uses the CAXIS function to change the "brightness" of a colour map. I have no experience in Matlab but it appears that they use this function to "lower" the intensity requirements needed for pixels to be mapped to a more intense colour on the map

i.e. Colour map using "JET"

- When brightness = 1, red = 255
- When brightness = 10, red >= 25

The matlab program allows 16bit images to be read in and displayed which obviouly gives higher pixel values whereas everything i've read and done indicates OpenCV only supports 8 bit images (for colour maps)

**Therefore my question is, is it possible to provide similar functionality in OpenCV? How do you set the axis limit for a colourmap/how do you scale the colour map lookup table so that "less" intense pixels are scaled to the more intense regions?**

A similar question was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822343/equivalent-of-matlab-s-caxis-in-opencv) with a reply stating the array needs to be "normalised" but unfortunately I don't quite know how to achieve this and can't reply to the answer as i don't have enough rep!

I have gone ahead and used [cv::normalize](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd) to set the max value in the array to be maxPixelValue/brightness but that doesn't work at all.

I have also experimented and tried converting my 16bit image into a CV_8UC1 with a scale factor to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to replicate the MATLAB behaviour but had to resort to manually iterating over each pixel and setting the value to the maximum value for the image depth or scaling the value where needed.

my code looked something like this

```
cv::minMaxLoc(dst, &min, &max);

double axisThreshold = floor(max / contrastLevel);

 for (int i = 0; i < dst.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dst.cols; j++)
        {
            short pixel = dst.at<short>(i, j);
            if (pixel >= axisThreshold)
            {
                pixel = USHRT_MAX;
            }
            else
            {
                pixel *= (USHRT_MAX / axisThreshold);
            }
            dst.at<short>(i, j) = cv::saturate_cast<short>(pixel);
        }
    }
```

In my example I had a slider which adjusted the contrast/brightness (we called it contrast, the original implementation called it brightness).

When the contrast/brightness was changed, the program would retrieve the maximum pixel value and then compute the axis limit by doing

calculatedThreshold = Max pixel value / contrast

Each pixel more than the threshold gets set to MAX, each pixel lower than the threshold gets multiplied by a scale factor calculated by

scale = MAX Pixel Value / calculatedThreshold.

TBH i can't say I fully understand the maths behind it. I just used trial and error until it worked; any help in that department would be appreciated HOWEVER it seems to do what i want to!

My understanding of the initial matlab implementation and the terminology "brightness" is in fact their attempt to scale the colourmap so that the "brighter" the image, the less intense each pixel had to be to map to a particular colour in the colourmap.

Since applycolourmap only works on 8 bit images, when the brightness increases and the colourmap axis values decrease, we need to ensure the values of the pixels scale accordingly so that they now match up with the "higher" intensity values in the map.

I have seen numerous OPENCV tutorials which use this approach to changing the contrast/brightness but they often promote the use of optimised convertTo (especially if you're trying to use the GPU). However as far as I can see, convertTo applies the aplha/beta values uniformly and not on a pixel by pixel basis therefore I can't use that approach.

I will update this question If i found more suitable OPENCV functions to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can use `cv::normalize` to "crop" values in the source picture to the corresponding ones in color map you are interested in. Say you want your image to be mapped to the blue-ish region of Jet colormap then you should do something like:

```
int minVal = 0, maxVal = 80;
cv::normalize(src,dst, minVal, maxVal, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
```

If you plan to apply some kind of custom map it's fairly easy for 1-or3-channel 8-bit image, you only need to create LUT with 255 values (with proper number of channels) and apply it using `cv::LUT`, more about it [in this blog](https://www.learnopencv.com/applycolormap-for-pseudocoloring-in-opencv-c-python/), also see the [dosc about LUT](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab55b8d062b7f5587720ede032d34156f)

If the image you are working is of different depth, 16-bit or even floating point data I guess all you need to do is write a function like:

```
template<class T> 
T customColorMapper(T input_pixel)
{
    T output_pixel = 0;
    // do something with output_pixel basing on intput_pixel
    return output_pixel;
}
```

and apply it to each source image pixel like:

```
cv::Mat dst_image = src_image.clone(); //copy data
dst_image.forEach<TYPE>([](TYPE& input_pixel, const int* pos_row_col) -> void {
    input_pixel = customColorMapper<TYPE>(input_pixel);
});
```

of course `TYPE` need to be a valid type. Maybe specialized version of this function taking `cv::Scalar` or `cv::Vec3`-something would be nice if you need to work with multiple channels.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I tried some of the techniques you mentioned but to no avail. Unfortunately I'm having to be a little vague with the requirements otherwise I would have shared more code/printscreens.

I did manage to get it working through!

I resorted to using a manual loop setting each pixel to the MAX value if it was more than the calculated threshold, if not i multiplied by a scale factor. See my updated post for more info.